# How to configure openfire to support TLS 1.2

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I'm using Openfire 3.8.1 as XMPP server on windows, but open fire supports only TLS 1.0 and i need support for TLS 1.2

How can i configure Openfire to support TLS 1.2?

Also i read that openfire is compiled with jdk 1.5 or 1.6 and those versions of jdk don't support TLS 1.2. If I compile openfire sources with jdk 1.7 that support TLS 1.2 will it be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Change the JRE Openfire is using from 1.6 to 1.7. If you are running Openfire in Windows, create a batch file that uses Java 7, based on the shell script openfirectl. There is no need to recompile the code.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to upgrade from 1.6 (e.g. openjdk-6) to 1.7 (e.g. openjdk-7) to get TLS 1.2.

Note that even with openjdk-7, TLS 1.2 is still disabled for client connections:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#tlsprotonote

> Although SunJSSE in the Java SE 7 release supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, neither version is enabled by default for client connections. Some servers do not implement forward compatibility correctly and refuse to talk to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 clients. For interoperability, SunJSSE does not enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 by default for client connections.

This means that for server-to-server connections, where openfire is acting as a client, it will still not use TLS 1.2 even with openjdk-7 (only in openjdk-8 would TLS 1.2 be finally enabled by default).

I've looked at the source code of openfire and the Java API, and made a conclusion that you should be able to fix the issue with the following (although I haven't had the chance to confirm it having the desired effect):

```
INSERT INTO OFPROPERTY VALUES('xmpp.socket.ssl.algorithm','TLSv1.2')
```

E.g. your best bet is to go with either Java 7 or 8, then if going with 7, try the above setting, too.